# Does English allow /eɪʃ/ in the end of a syllable (in the same syllable)?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, phonotactics

The sound /ʃ/ is almost always spelled with more than one letter i.e. with a [digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography)) unlike, say, /p/ which is spelled with a single letter (***p**an, **p**en, **p**ie*). I have noticed a particular pattern: vowels before digraphs are usually short and **not** long (or diphthongs). The /ʃ/ sound is spelled with a digraph so I assume the vowel before "sh" is usually short. Other sounds such as /p/ (*shape*), /t/ (*hate*), /k/ (*make*) and even /tʃ/ (*aitch*) can occur *after* /eɪ/.

Also notice that **/-eɪk/** is never, in my opinion, spelled with **-ck**.

It may seem to be confusing spelling and pronunciation but both of them are closely related to each other. If English allows **/eɪʃ/** in the end of the same syllable (or in the end of a word), then it might be possible to have a long vowel/ diphthong before the digraph "sh". However, I haven't been able to find any word in which /ʃ/ is spelled with a digraph and has a long vowel/ diphthong before it which led my to my question:

- **Does English allow /eɪʃ/ in the same syllable?**

Comment: The *word* ends with a schwa, but it seems to me the first syllable of ***fascia*** qualifies here

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I had never heard that word before. Cambridge Dictionary gives /ˈf**eɪ.ʃ**ə/ and both the diphthong and /ʃ/ belong to separate syllables. My question is specifically about "syllable ending position" [same syllable] (there are many consonant clusters and/or vowel consonant combos that are not allowed in a single syllable but allowed across syllables e.g. /gn/ does not occur in the same syllable but occurs across syllable boundary as in *ma**g.n**et*).

Comment: Also see *facial* and *spatial*; but the diphthong and the "sh" belong to separate syllables.

Comment: The Longman Pronunciation  Dictionary gives /ˈfeɪʃ.ə/ for "fascia".

Comment: I must admit I'm surprised to see how many different phonetic variations ***fascia*** has in the full OED - **/ˈfeɪʃ(ɪ)ə/, /ˈfeɪsɪə/, /ˈfeɪʃ(i)ə/, /ˈfaʃ(ɪ)ə/, /ˈfæʃ(i)ə/**. Where I *think* my version is first in the list (except I don't understand **(ɪ)** there, and I'm not good with IPA in the first place). For me, ***fascia*** rhymes with relaxed speech *I'll race you = I'll **race ya***. But let's not forget ***racial** discrimination*, which is on everybody's lips these days.

Comment: Yes, English does allow /eɪʃ/ in syllable-final position. If you still want /-eɪʃ/ in the same syllable, then there's *seiche* /seɪʃ/ and *crèche* /kreɪʃ/ (also /-kreʃ/).

Comment: If you want a word with an actual "sh" before the long vowel, there's [naish](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naish).

Comment: "Cache" is often (mis)pronounced with the same vowel as "make", especially in computing, although most dictionaries suggest the same vowel as "cat". Hence it would qualify as an example of "eɪʃ" being possible.

Comment: @StuartF - I’ve never once heard cache pronounced (computing or not) with the same vowel as make *except in locales where the word cash is also pronounced with the “make” vowel*.

Comment: @Jim It's maybe a regional thing: Americans seem to mispronounce cache as cachet; here's an Australian forum discussion which is heavily pro-caysh (make-vowel). https://forums.overclockers.com.au/threads/how-is-cache-pronounced.418015/

Comment: @StuartF I'll wager that many people who have heard the word "cache" don't know it's spelled that way, so when they see the written word they don't realize it's the that word. It probably looks to them like a borrowed French word that would originally have ended with "é".

Comment: And others who see the word think the "e" at the end is like the "e" in "cake", "rope", and "dupe", turning the previous vowel into its long form.

Comment: The question comes from a false presupposition -- that English spelling has something to do with English pronunciation. However many letters something is spelled with /ʃ/ (two in English,, one in Hungarian,  either one or three in German (depending on whether it comes before a stop or not), there is no connection with vowel length (English has no long vowels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start by saying this is not a very answerable question.

- For one thing, it's far from obvious that rules about what "English allows" are 100% knowable. Some sequences of sounds exist in only one or a handful of words; e.g. the Wikipedia page [List of English words without rhymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_without_rhymes#Masculine_rhymes) gives *gouge, scarce, ninth* as the only words ending in the rimes /ˈ-ɛərs/, /ˈ-aʊdʒ/, /ˈ-aɪnθ/.

  This suggests that there might be many "accidental gaps" in attested sequences of sounds: sequences where it is just chance that no word, rather than one or more words, contains the sequence. I believe the existence of accidental gaps in syllable rimes is widely assumed by linguists, although people may differ in what they consider to fall in this category.
- The other issue is that there is no perfect definition of what it means to be an English word, so you'll run into problems with deciding things like whether *[Kshatriya](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Kshatriya),* which has an entry in Merriam-Webster with a pronunciation transcribed as starting with /kʃ/, counts as proof that "English allows" /kʃ/ at the start of a syllable, or *[iamb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iamb),* which has an entry showing a pronunciation ending in /mb/, counts as proof that English allows /mb/ at the end of a syllable.

My view is that it makes more sense to say that English does allow /eɪʃ/ at the end of syllables than to say that it doesn't.

- I'm an English speaker, and I don't find it difficult or particularly remarkable to pronounce a syllable ending in /eɪʃ/
- There is a name Naish that seems to be pronounced at least sometimes with /eɪʃ/: listen to these [Youglish results for Naish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/Naish./english?)
- It is found in the humorous clipping "vacaysh" from "vacation"

A comment on your description "vowels before digraphs are usually short and not long." As you point out, this is a spelling-based rule, so it isn't directly relevant to phonotactic rules, which are conceived of by linguists as rules about phonemes. In any case, there are a non-negligible amount of exceptions to this generalization, such as *truth, Ruth, faith, speech.*